# Multiple columns to UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, multiple-columns

I am loading data into an array from MySQL, and I would like to populate them in `UITableCiew`. How can I add multiple columns (in my case 4) to `UITableView`?

I was able to load the row data but I do not understand how I can divide it up into columns. Is `UICollectionView` an option? If it is, how can I go about it?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't modify the behavior of table views in Xcode itself unless you obtain the source code of Xcode and recompile it. Did you mean, by accident, to do it within **your app?**

Comment: yup..i want to do it in my app..

Comment: Please then read the tag wiki for `xcode`. Generally, you should **not** use this tag.

Comment: i am currently considering this.. http://usxue.is-programmer.com/posts/14176.html but is this a good way?? and could someone direct me to its source code..i couldnt find it..

Comment: i am sorry..i am new here..will take it off..

Comment: Just add 4 "subcells" in each `UITableViewCell`, giving them fixed widths and maybe solid left/right edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is available in **Available in iOS 6.0 and later** and therefore cannot be used if you want to support earlier version. 
And as per your requirement you need to display a **GridView**

So to support earlier versions and get other cool features you can use other libraries here are some of the options:

1) [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView)

2) [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)

3) [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

4) [NRGridView](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView)

5) [MMGridView](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView)

6) [WCGridView](https://github.com/wess/WCGridView)

I am currently using **`AQGridView`** so surely i recommend that as it is the least buggy and its functions are very similar to `UITableView`.

Also that If you are trying to do this without **XIB** it will be little bit difficult for you to handle it but you can create a view controller with Xib file to Create the interface of your choice. [Here is the Video of how it can be done in the best possible way](http://vimeo.com/46408155) by  `Evadne Wu`. And [here](https://github.com/evadne/gridViewNibTest) is the Sample Project

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for something like this:

[image]

You should definitely check this awesome post: 
http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

Also you can directly go to their source code from here:
https://github.com/brightec/CustomCollectionViewLayout

Implemented in obj-c both they recently migrated to swift. They are using UICollectionView as you can see the details from the post.

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` is correct option. Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) for details. 
Its functioning is similar to tableView with delegate, datasource, numberOfSections Rows etc. Just read that document, you will understand. If you find any problem put your code. Will help.

Comment: yes please..would you be able to give me a code snippet i can build on to create a simple table(multiple columns) using uicollectionview ..Thanks!!