# Multiple Columns In UITableView in Swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I am creating an app using Xcode 6, using Swift. I am using a Table View, and need two columns. How would I create a Table View with 2 columns?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257970/multiple-columns-to-uitableview-in-ios You'd need to use a UICollectionView, or a 3rd-party library instead. UITableView only works with rows - not columns.

Comment: or you could have two table views?

Comment: Use UICollectionView